# Scrapy Redirect in python

Tags: python, redirect, web-crawler, scrapy

I am a bit new to the Scrapy framework. I want to scrape a web page that takes me through the result page through a Redirect.

1. The search form is in my start URL.
2. Parse Method: I take the response and use

   ```
   FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata=values,
                             callback=self.handle_redirect)
   ```

   to generate a request with all the values needed to post the url.
3. This request goes to the 302 (object Moved) page. Once there, I don't want to scrape any more data.

I want to redirect to the original page where there are search results.

How should I approach this?

Comment: So at step 3 you end up at an unwanted page, and you need Scrapy to go elsewhere?

Comment: at setp 3 i want scrapy to donot redirect me. i want it to give me the first page after my post request. but in this case i get the second page after post pack.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me. Can you add the URL's you are posting to, in your original question so I can get more familiar with the flow and the problem you are having?

Comment: thanks for your reply Sjaak!!! Kindly tell me one thing.... i want to request a form 26x26 = times.... its very large no of time. i want to store all the post request objects in the list and yield them with time to time.... how to see this approch?